# Actionscript-collision detection for text in textfields

Tags: actionscript-3, text, collision-detection, textfield

Creating an application that will randomize signatures (textfields) on a page. Is there any way for collision detection to work with text in textfields?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried with hittest using following code and it tests as true as soon as cursor enters the textfield bounds. Is that acceptable or you want hittest to fire only if over text (not the whole text field).

```
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, frameMove);
// hit test on  every frame
function frameMove(e:Event){
    if(dt_txt.hitTestPoint(mouseX, mouseY, true))
        state_txt.text = "ON";
    else
        state_txt.text = "OFF";
}
```

in the `hitTestPoint` function it doesnt matter if I specify the shape flag as true or false, in both cases the hittest fires as soon as cursor enters TextField Bounds

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, but no, need to detect if and when 2 text fields overlap...just getting the bunds may work for me.

As an alternative, may employ Box2D, just for its collision detection and render each textfield inside a rectangle polygon.